# If X and Y are two positive random variables, and $\operatorname{E}[X] \leq \operatorname{E}[Y]$ the $P(X \geq Y) \leq 1/2$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

An interesting observation is made as follows:

If there are two positive random variables $X$ and $Y$, such that $\operatorname{E}[X] \leq \operatorname{E}[Y]$ then the probability of $X > Y$ should not be more than half else the precondition would not hold.

However, I have not been able to prove the same. Is the statement wrong or provable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not been able to prove it because it's not true.

Let $X$ follow your favourite distribution on $(0,\infty)$ with full support and finite first moment (the exponential distribution will do) and let $Y$ have the distribution

$$
P(Y=0)=1-P(Y=10^6 E[X])=1-10^{-3}.
$$
Then, no matter the coupling between $X$ and $Y$, $$P(X>Y)\geq P(Y=0)=1-10^{-3}>\frac{1}{2}$$ However,
$$
E[Y]=10^{-3}\cdot 10^6\cdot E[X]>E[X]
$$

Comment: Big numbers chosen to indicate that no version of this statement is true. Information about the first moments of $X$ and $Y$ does not give you information on the event $(X>Y)$, even when $X$ and $Y$ are positive.

Comment: A follow-up question, if we had the moment generating function for both the random variables, would it be possible to prove a similar statement?

Comment: What assumptions are you putting on the MGFs? In the above, if $X$ is exponential, then both $X$ and $Y$ have exponential moments, so their MGFs are well-defined.

Comment: Both have their MGFs as the sum of two Erlang Distributions and hence, their MGFs are well defined.

Comment: More formally, the MGF for X is $\left(1-\frac{t}{\alpha  \beta }\right)^{-f} \left(1-\frac{t}{\alpha  \lambda }\right)^{h-k}$ and that of Y is $\frac{\beta  \left(1-\frac{t}{\lambda }\right)^{-f k}}{\beta -t}$ for some parameters $\alpha, \beta, \lambda, k, h$

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking at this point. Are you asking whether your assumption is true for variables in a specific class of distributions? And if so, how are you coupling them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128377/discussion-between-ajainuary-and-woolierthanthou).